# Flask App Error while deploying to Heroku at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/". I'm using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, heroku

The sample flask app is giving error at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" while deploying in Heroku.

I changed the Procfile as many times as I got an error, but there are no better results.

run.py

```
import os

from flask_minify  import Minify

from apps import create_app
app = create_app()

DEBUG = app.config['DEBUG'] 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

Error Coming:

```
Process exited with status 1
2022-10-21T02:30:41.744294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-21T02:30:58.387078+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=1dba507d-117f-47e9-8395-16452f0ec2ab fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:30:59.567432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=be0decff-7481-4c97-95ce-6be3705e8d37 fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:32:19.232749+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=addba986-cc24-4218-b42a-a9629368288e fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:32:19.740963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=6652df66-1dc8-43dd-adf4-f57800563199 fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:36:35.452710+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=28e38bc6-f861-4f88-a260-e463d6c4088e fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:36:36.523511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=e3b958b2-3735-4a4f-a2b5-eb05efba2921 fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:46:33.625471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=130a28f7-a437-4fdf-9608-8ef3b9697f13 fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:46:35.058128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=f083adb6-466a-47cf-9697-dd2ece77043f fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:47:22.882529+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=370b8b2c-2d90-4abb-8904-59bba31961da fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-21T02:47:22.280523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=increhub.herokuapp.com request_id=dfad6625-cdaf-4396-85cc-d732e69dfada fwd="106.79.203.182" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think your issue is in the Procfile.**

Try changing it to:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT flaskapp:app
```

Another useful command would be:

```
web: gunicorn flaskapp.wsgi --log-file-
```

**Let me know if this helped. Most of the times, this error is caused by a misconfigured Procfile. I'd suggest you definitely look into that.**

Comment: Just realized, if that doesn't help, try having a Procfile with this 2 lines:

`web: gunicorn app:app`
`web: gunicorn run:app`

**In any case, you should check the log files to better understand the error obtained**